# foreignObject SVG Element only display plain text

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

The following foreignobject code is not displaying html element but only plain text:

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" xmlns:pidoco="http://www.pidoco.com/util">
    <foreignObject width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p style="color: red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">text</p>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
```

Instead of getting a colored text, I get nothing (white area). Even if when I remove the body and p tag and only add a text node the foreign element it still stay white.

When I remove body, p tag and the attribute requiredExtensions then I get the plain text.

The g tag is working correctly because other svg elements can be rendered.

How can I get all my html displaying correctly?

I'm using Chrome 37.

EDIT:

I'm creating the foreign object with the following JavaScript Code

```
    var foreignObject = rabbit.util.createElement("foreignObject", {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        requiredExtensions: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    });

    var body = rabbit.util.createElement("body", {
        xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    });

    var p = rabbit.util.createElement("p", {
        style: "color: red",
        xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    });
    var textContent = document.createTextNode("text");

    p.appendChild(textContent);
    body.appendChild(p);
    foreignObject.appendChild(body);
    group.appendChild(foreignObject);
```

Comment: You've put text in it, what exactly do you expect. Also stroke-width does not apply to html text FWIW.

Comment: You pointed me to the right thing. `rabbit.util.createElement` was using `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", name);` which is wrong because `<body>` shouldn't have the svg namespace. I correct it by passing the correct namespace, now it's working as expected. Thanks you very much.